# Check if option is selected Form cakephp 3

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I have a form for selecting Types. Each type has a color associated.
In my TypesController, I have a function related to a view :

```
$types = $this->Types->find('list')->select(['id','name','color'])->toArray();
$this->set(compact(['types']));
```

And in my view, I can list every types in a select :

```
echo $this->Form->select('type_id', $types,['empty'=>'Types','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'types']);
```

I would like to show the type's color when user selects a type. Only when an option is selected. Is it possible? I tried with JS but it didn't work. 
Color is hexadecimal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where do you want to show the color when it is selected?

Comment: Just next to select box if possible

Comment: And what is the format of `color`? Hexadecimal?

Comment: Yes absolutely, hexa

Comment: I see a `form-control` class, are you using jQuery / bootstrap?

Comment: Both, bootstrap and ajax for sending datas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not use `find('list')` since it returns key/value pairs, you want to use (e.g.):

```
$types = $this->Types->find()->select(['id','name','color'])->toArray();
```

Then in your view, you want to be able to store the `color` attributes, so e.g.:

```
// Convert your $types array to something we can send to `select`
$options = array_map(function ($e) {
    return [
        'value' => $e->id,
        'text'  => $e->name,
        'templateVars' => [
            'color' => $e->color
        ]
    ];
}, $types);
// Use a custom template for the `option` element to store the color as a data- attribute
$this->Form->templates([
    'option' => '<option value="{{value}}" data-color="{{color}}"{{attrs}}>{{text}}</option>'
]);
// Create the select element
echo $this->Form->select('type', $options, [
    'empty'=>'Types', 'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'types'
]);
```

See [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-additional-template-variables-to-templates) if you don' t know what are additional template variables (`templateVars` ) - You need CakePHP 3.1+ to use `templateVars`.

You will get something like:

```
<select name="type" class="form-control form-control" id="types">
    <option value="" data-color="">Types</option>
    <option value="1" data-color="ff0000">Red</option>
    <option value="2" data-color="0000ff">Blue</option>
    <option value="3" data-color="00ff00">Green</option>
</select>
```

For the following, I am assuming you have an element with `id="color-preview"`  in which you want to set the background color, e.g.:

```
<div id="color-preview"></div>
```

Here is what the javascript code would look like (with jQuery):

```
$('#types').on('change', function () {
    var opt = $(this).find(':selected');
    var col = '';
    if (opt.data('color')) {
        col = '#' + opt.data('color');
    }
    $('#color-preview').css({background: col});
});
```

Without jQuery (modern browser only):

```
var previewDiv = document.getElementById('color-preview');
document.getElementById('types').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    var col = '';
    if (opt.dataset.color) {
        col = '#' + opt.dataset.color;
    }
    previewDiv.style.background = col;
});
```

Comment: Ok it works perfectly, thanks! I only replaced `col = '#' + opt.dataset.color;` by `col = opt.dataset.color;` because I'm storing # too in database. Perfect, thanks a lot for your help.